# White screen when combining ReactJS + Marzipano?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, 360-panorama

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to combine [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) + [Marzipano](http://www.marzipano.net/).

I'm at the stage where I've created my React project using `create-react-app`, installed Marzipano via npm, and copied / *slightly* modified some boilerplate code from a Marzipano example [here](http://www.marzipano.net/demos/equirect/index.html) to get it to fit into the React app.

Note I also installed [glslify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glslify) as a dependency in my project, because when I tried to import Marzipano without it, I got the following error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'glslify'

Note also that glslify is a dev dependency for Marzipano, but not a production one. I'm thinking by installing it as a dependency may be where I tripped things up, but it was throwing the above error without it so not sure what to make of that.

Anyways what's happening now is my browser is rendering a white screen with no errors in the console, however when you click and drag the cursor changes to a closed hand, and the `div` that I attached Marzipano to via React's `ref` system has been modified, so Marzipano is definitely doing something.

Below is my App.js file (everything else is a fresh `create-react-app` installation):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Marzipano from 'marzipano';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.panoViewer = new Marzipano.Viewer(this.pano);

    // Create source.
    const source = Marzipano.ImageUrlSource.fromString(
      "img/test.jpg"
    );

    // Create geometry.
    const geometry = new Marzipano.EquirectGeometry([{ width: 2048 }]);

    // Create view.
    const limiter = Marzipano.RectilinearView.limit.traditional(1024, 100*Math.PI/180);
    const view = new Marzipano.RectilinearView({ yaw: Math.PI }, limiter);

    // Create scene.
    const scene = this.panoViewer.createScene({
      source: source,
      geometry: geometry,
      view: view,
      pinFirstLevel: true
    });

    // Display scene.
    scene.switchTo();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div ref={pano => this.pano = pano} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first (and only) time the render method is called, the div which you attach the ref to has no content and therefore is rendered with a height of zero.

Marzipano then creates the scene in this div, but as it reads the dimensions of the container element, it renders a canvas with zero height.

To fix this, either set a specific height on the div (for example using the style attribute) or give it a height of 100% and do the same in index.css for html, body and #root

Comment: This was the solution to my problem as well trying to get Marzipano working with Vue.js.  At least over this part.  Bravo.